# Read from RS232 and send command trought php url

Tags: php, serial-port

i need to create a project where, based on info read from RS232 port, i need to execute an appropriate url to update a mysql db on a REMOVE server.

I think best hardware is a rasperry or mini-pc connected to internet. Is it true?

The only thing is that i don't know how to start to write a script for this purpose. What language?

I work only with php/javascript :(

For example if I receive data on my RS232 port with:

```
110111 ------> then execute url http://www.test.com/update.php?id=5&qty=1

100011 ------> then execute url http://www.test.com/update.php?id=6&qty=3

etc...
```

Url is only for update a mysql database on a webserver, so i don't need to get any result.

Anyone can suggest me how to start and if there are some examples for my purpose, online?

UPDATE: I try to explain better my purpose: We have a CASH BOX where, where when the receipt is printed, send also information about the products bought, trought rs232 output. For example PRODUCT XX, QUANTITY 5, PRICE 40.00, ID = 1
With this info I need to syncronize/update an online mysql database. Only way to update my database online is execute/visit url like: http://www.test.com/update.php?id=1&qty=5
So... i know that PHP can't read lowlevel HW so I can't read a com port directly with PHP.
My idea was to connect a raspberry (with a rs232 port) and create a pyton script that read rs232 and based on info received (ID and QUANTITY for my use), create the appropriate url and execute it.

Comment: IT#s absolutely not clear what you are asking. Please edit.

Comment: tried to add an explanation

Comment: So the question is. "Can I use a serial port with PHP?"?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes it can be the question. But i've read several times that PHP CAN'T access easily to read/write HARDWARE in general... so my final question is: are there some trick using alternative devices (i think raspberry, or arduino is a valid solution) to convert a rs232 input to a url to be executed without pain?

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini It seems like you don't know what language you should use for that application. If I where you I would write a c# program since I already dealt with serial ports in c#. If you don't have any experience in c# or any other object oriented programming language you might look into python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP I found something, but the site is in German:
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/101642

I'll try to translate the code and comments for you.

```
<?php


//function to select the serial port
function rs232init($com,$bautrate)
{
    `mode $com: BAUD=$bautrate PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off`;
}

//function for sending
function send($comport,$character)
{
    $fp = fopen ("$comport", "w+");
    if (!$fp)
    {
        echo "Port is not opened for sending!";
    }
    else 
    {
        fputs ($fp, $character);
        fclose ($fp);
    }
}

//function for reading
function read($comport2,$seconds)
{

    $buffer = "";

    $fp2 = fopen ("$comport2", "r+");
    if (!$fp2)
    {
        echo "Port is not opened for reading!";
    }
    else
    {
        sleep($seconds);
        $buffer .= fgets($fp2, 4096);
    }
    return $buffer;
    fclose ($fp2);
}

// Example calls

rs232init("com2","9600"); // open Com2 with bautrate 9600
sending("com2","hello");  // send “hello” with comport2 
$read = read("com2","2"); // read 2 seconds from Comport2 and write the result in variable $read
echo $read ;   „“         // print variable $read

?>
```

I don't know if that code works, but I hope I was able to help you a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and i'll do some tests.

Comment: How are the Tests going? Was this helpful?

Comment: hi i'm actually in "standby" with this project. i'll update this post asap.

Comment: I've tried your code but I always get: Port is not opened for reading. I'm using WAMP for localhost under Windows 10. Using com1

Comment: is com1 the name of your serial port? you should be able to see it in the device manager

Comment: and you call `rs232init("com1","9600"); $read = read("com1","2");` Maybe you need to call COM1 I'm not totally sure.